# Можно ли узнать уровень вложенности и вывод продуктов от несколько категории?

Tags: opencart, 1с

Столкнулся с 2 проблемами:

1. Продукты получаем из `1c`, уровень вложенности там просто огромный. Решили сократить. Вопрос: можно ли получить в переменную на каком уровне вложенности мы сейчас находимся?
2. Если есть следующая структура: `Каталог - Фаст фуд` и в фаст фуде идут такие категории как бургеры, хот доги и.т.п. Вопрос: можно ли вывести в категорию фаст фуд все продукты что относятся непосредственно к дочерним категориям?

Comment: Можно.Получите список дочерних категорий и выполните запрос с их учетом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - `$this->request->request['path']` (и вы уже задавали вопросы, где видно, как в path записана вложенность (`...&path=1_9_10_11)...`))

2 - необходимо изменить запрос в `model/catalog/product.php/getProducts()` на участке `if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {` или изначально при импорте товаров из 1с затаскивать их с указанием не только своей, но и родительской категории(категорий)